# Error: Missing \endcsname inserted.<to be read again> \tex_let:D \begin{}

Tags: templates

I'm using texmaker 4.5. I'm trying to compile the following text on Windows 10:

```
\documentclass[english]{MastersDoctoralThesis} 
\begin{document}
\frontmatter 
\begin{titlepage}

    The Title.

\end{titlepage}
\begin{declaration}

    The Declaration.

\end{declaration}
\end{document}
```

But when I compile it, the following error appears:

```
''! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\tex_let:D
\begin{document}''
```

How can I solve it?

---

The template can be found at: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example minimal (not using any special class and too much unnecessary informationg). It shall be compilable.

Comment: The problem does not seem to be in the part that you show us. If I take the first `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls` that Google offers (there is no standard class of this name, so you have to tell us which one you use) the document compiles without problems.

Comment: The problem is related to the latest update to `xparse` which is used inside, but the main cause is the wrong usage of `\NewDocumentCommand` etc. by the author of the MDT class.

Comment: http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=29178

Comment: Try `\makeatletter
    \AtBeginDocument{
      \renewcommand{\blank@p@gestyle}{empty}
    }
    \makeatother`

Comment: If the OP would have left the comment header, nobody here would have had any need to use google.

Comment: With \makeatletter \AtBeginDocument{ \renewcommand{\blank@p@gestyle}{empty} } \makeatother it compile correctly. Thank you very much

Answer (score 10):

**Update: 2017/03/09** With the new update of `xparse` and `expl3` packages from 2017/03/07 it is possible to use commands defined with  `\DeclareDocumentCommand` in `\csname ...\endcsname` constructs ago, which is the case in the background code of `\pagestyle, for example.

The `\blank@p@gestyle` macro is defined in `MDT` with `\DeclareDocumentCommand` which isn't expandable, but `\pagestyle` needs an expandable name, so this fails.

With this bypassing code

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand{\blank@p@gestyle}{empty}
}
\makeatother
```

the macro is exandable again.

A future release of `xparse` will remove the necessity of this bypass.

This tiny document shows the same error (and is the short version of what happens)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{empty}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{\foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean it will remove the need for the bypass? What you say right now means it will break when it is updated ....

Comment: @cfr Means L3 team decided to go a step backward not to break peoples code,  on the other hand, i guess the template will be updated to not need that bypass.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, but that's not what the answer *says*.

Comment: @cfr Not what it says, but what it was meant to say. Maybe Christian needs to reword stuff.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Reworded

Comment: Not only the next update of `xparse`, but the template wil be, i hope so, updated as well.

Comment: Thanks for rewording. (I would upvote, but I already did.)

Answer (score 5):

The template shows a few wrong usages of `\NewDocumentCommand` and `\DeclareDocumentCommand`.

For instance,

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\supervisor}{m}{%
  \DeclareDocumentCommand{\supname}{}{#1}%
}
```

(code reformatted for readability) should be

```
\newcommand\supname{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\supervisor}{m}{%
  \renewcommand\supname{#1}%
}
```

because `\supname` is just a variable, not a *document command*. Better, using `expl3` programming, assuming `\ExplSyntaxOn` is in force,

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\supervisor}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \supname { #1 }
 }
```

Better yet,

```
\tl_new:Nn \g_mdt_supname_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\supervisor}{m}
 {
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_mdt_supname_tl { #1 }
 }
```

and, if `\supname` is allowed to be used in the document,

```
\cs_new:Npn \supname { \tl_use:N \g_mdt_supname_tl }
```

The particular problem stems from

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\blank@p@gestyle}{}{empty}
```

which should be

```
\tl_set:Nn \blank@p@gestyle { empty }
```

or, using traditional programming,

```
\newcommand\blank@p@gestyle{empty}
```

because the argument to `\pagestyle` should be fully expandable, which something defined by `\NewDocumentCommand` isn't.

Similarly,

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\setblankpagestyle}{ m }{%
  \DeclareDocumentCommand{\blank@p@gestyle}{}{#1}%
}
```

should be

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\setblankpagestyle}{ m }
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \blank@p@gestyle { #1 }
 }
```

or, in traditional programming,

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\setblankpagestyle}{ m }{%
  \renewcommand\blank@p@gestyle{#1}%
}
```